# What is the difference between extract () function and associatve array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, extract

I want to know what is the difference between extract() function  and associative array () function in php. Where do i use this?

```
$state = array("AS"=>"ASSAM", "OR"=>"ORRISA", "KR"=>"KERELA"); 
extract($state); 
echo"\$AS is $AS <br/>\n\$KR is $KR <br/>\n\$OR is $OR <br/>";
```

instead of this line if i am writting echo `"$state[AS]";` then i am getting same result but what is difference ?

Comment: o.O what.. there is no associative array function.. just simply arrays. Whether they're numerically indexed or labelled defines the type of array ..

Comment: The extract function can be called *on* an array (associative arrays will set a variable with the index as the name, and the value of the element as the value of the array). It's probably not a good practice to use `extract()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "where do i use this"? What exactly is "this"?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would say don't use extract.
It's usually better to keep all the values inside the array since you can loop an array.

With variables you don't know how many got created with the extraction. Was it only one value in the array or 50?
If it's in the array you can count and loop them, in variables you need to test if each variable is set or not.

Also using extract will overwrite your variables if you are unlucky.

```
// Some calculations result in a price
$price = 500;

// Now you get an array from user input or json and extract it
$array = ["something" => "here", "price" => 10];
extract($array);

// Extracting overwrites your $price with value 10!
echo $price; // 10
```

Let's say we use the above scenario again but without the extract.

```
// Some calculations result in a price
$price = 500;

// Now you get an array from user input or json
$array = ["something" => "here", "price" => 10];


echo $price; // 500
echo $array['price']; // 10
```

Now we have both the array value and your value.
Nothing is compromised as we are in control of where the values go.
But as soon as you use extract, you really unleash everything and can only hope for the best.

TL/DR;

Don't use extract. If you do need to/want to use it, then only use extract on your own arrays that you have 100% control of.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the answer given by @Andreas, i.e. avoid using `extract` where you can, as you may end up overwriting your variables. One thing not mentioned in the answer, however, is that you can avoid overwriting your variables with the use of the `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME` flag.

```
 $price = 500;
 $quantity = 1;

 $array = ["something" => "here", "price" => 10, "quantity" => 2];
 extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, 'new');

 echo $price; // 500
 echo $something; // here
 echo $quantity; // 1
 echo $new_price; // 10
 echo $new_quantity // 2
```

Of course, with a large array, this may leave you wondering which of the variables, if any, have been allocated the prefix. You could create an array of these variables in order to find out...

```
print_r(array_filter(get_defined_vars(), function($key) {
        if(substr($key, 0, 4) == 'new_') return 1;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));

// output
Array
(
    [new_price] => 10
    [new_quantity] => 2
)
```

.... or loop through for the same result. Of course, if you were really unlucky, you could still end up overwriting your variables with this technique!

One thing to bear in mind is that `extract()` will only create or overwrite variables in the current scope. That means you could do the desired work within a local scope.

```
function getBillsInfo($aboutBill) {
    extract( $aboutBill);
    echo ("I'm " . $firstName); // I'm Bill
}

$firstName = 'Bob';

$aboutBill = [
    'firstName' => 'Bill',
    'surname' => 'Mcgill',
    'job' => 'grill',
    'location' => 'seville',
];

getBillsInfo($aboutBill);

echo '<pre>' , ("I'm still " . $firstName); // I'm still Bob
```

Ultimately, I do think `extract` has its place, but you need to be careful with its use.

To answer the question "What is the difference between `extract` function and associative array in php", directly, is a bit of an apples and oranges scenario. `extract` is an array function, designed to work on an array. Whereas an associative array is, well, an array (ordered map)!