# PHP get values from array

Tags: php, arrays

Im return an array from a function and I want to grabe the elements in the array and store them as varibles.

When I do a:

```
$array = fetchArray();
var_dump ($array);
```

I get this:

```
array(size = 1)
0 =>
    array(size = 1)
0 =>
    array(size = 7)
'customerid' => string '31' (length = 2)
'username' => string 'test' (length = 4)
'active' => string '1' (length = 1)
'CustomerName' => string 'Tobias Axbard' (length = 13)
'email' => string 'tobias.axbard@hotmail.com' (length = 25)
'phonenumber' => string '0738032207' (length = 10)
'isstaff' => string '0' (length = 1)
```

So than I would like to do something like this:

```
$username = $array["username"];
echo $username;
```

But insted of the string "test" from the array I get an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username
```

Any ides?

Comment: You can use the `PHP` array function `extract`. I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863467/what-is-the-difference-between-extract-function-and-associatve-array-in-php/68611093#68611093) which might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `$array` has two nested arrays inside it which you need to access:

```php
$username = $array[0][0]["username"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, youre array is nested, so an array in an array in an array.

Most outer array is `$array`.
The first element of $array, `$array[0]`, is an other array,
and that one contains again another one as first element `$array[0][0]` which contains the data you want to access.

So you'll have to use `$array[0][0]['username']` to access the values.

Use `$array = $array[0][0]` to 'move it up', or even use `extract($array[0][0])` to immediatly convert the array keys to variables:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php